# How to insert new data into a table, then insert new data again to that same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert-update

I don't know the correct term/word for this question, maybe stored procedure? so it may have been answered before. If so please kindly point me to the right direction or edit my question to make more sense.

But basically.

I have a table (call it 'customer') and I want to insert new data (call it 'newcustomers') into customer, which I do using the insert statement. Then the next day another batch of new data arrives and I would like to insert that new batch of data into 'customer' but underneath the previous data ('newcustomers').

My real question is, how do I do this without having to write an insert statement multiple times? I am also aware my IF OBJECT statement deletes the table everytime I execute the statement, reason being I wanted to try create a script that executes with one click of a button

Each day I would like to add new customers underneath the customer table and do this once, e.g. click execute once and the whole script will run/use an automated procedure to run it daily etc.

I don't know if I am thinking way outside the box and if there is a simple answer to this.

```
USE [customerdatabase]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER];

-- Create your table
CREATE TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]

(

  [Customer lastname] VARCHAR (MAX)
, [Customer firstname] VARCHAR (MAX)


)

-- This will insert data in to the created table from above.
BULK INSERT CUSTOMER FROM 'C:\Users\OriginalDATA.csv'
With 

(    
    FirstROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

-- Now we want to insert new data for the week.

IF OBJECT_ID('[customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers]', 'U') IS NOT 
NULL
DROP TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers];

CREATE TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers]

(

  [Customer lastname] VARCHAR (MAX)
, [Customer firstname] VARCHAR (MAX)

)

--This inserts new data seperately in to customerdatabase
BULK INSERT newcustomers FROM 'C:\Users\Downloads\neCustomer.csv'
With 

(    

FirstROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
SELECT * FROM newcustomers

-- repeat bulk insert again for next days batch of data
-- but do I do insert into again?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want to break your code into three scripts. One to create your tables, and a second one to populate the Customer table with initial data, and a third to populate the existing table with new entries.  (If you do it right, you'll only ever run the first and second scripts one time.  That is... until someone comes along and wants more fields to be captured... but that's a different question entirely.)

First Script:

```
USE [customerdatabase]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   begin
      DROP TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER];
      print 'Dropped Table [customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]';
   end
GO

-- Create your Permanent Customer table
CREATE TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]
   ([Customer lastname] VARCHAR (MAX)
   , [Customer firstname] VARCHAR (MAX)
   );
GO

-- Create your Staging Table for New customers.
IF OBJECT_ID('[customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   begin
      DROP TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers];
      print 'Dropped Table [customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers]';
   end
GO

CREATE TABLE [customerdatabase].[dbo].[newcustomers]
   ([Customer lastname] VARCHAR (MAX)
   , [Customer firstname] VARCHAR (MAX)
   );
GO
```

This gets your permanent table structure into your database.  Keep in mind, if you ever run it a second time, it will delete all your current data and replace it with empty tables.  So you only ever want to run this once.

Second Script:

```
USE [customerdatabase]
GO

-- This will insert data in to the already created Empty Customer table.
BULK INSERT [CUSTOMER] FROM 'C:\Users\OriginalDATA.csv'
With 
   (FirstROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   );
GO
```

This is also a one time event.  It populates your Customer Table with all the current customer data.  If you run this script again, you'll end up with duplicates in your table.  Probably not a good thing.

If your superiors ever give you a "New and Improved" OriginalDATA.CSV file that calls for you to eliminate all old data and import the improved data, you'll need to run script one and two again.  But that's time consumming and hopefully doesn't happen often (if at all).

Third Script:  (Actually a stored procedure)

```
USE [customerdatabase]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

if exists 
   (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects 
     WHERE id = object_id(N'[spAddNewCustomers]') and ObjectProperty(id,N'IsProcedure') = 1)
   begin
      drop procedure [spAddNewCustomers];
      print 'Dropped [procedure spAddNewCustomers]';
   end
GO

/****** Object: Stored Procedure [spAddNewCustomers] ******/

CREATE PROCEDURE [spAddNewCustomers]
   @pParameter1  varchar(max) = null  --Possible input parameter 1
   ,@pDebug bit = 0                   --Possible input parameter 2

AS

/*  Author   : Your Name
**  Date     : 2017-06-30
**  Name     : [spAddNewCustomers]
**  Called by: 
**  Purpose  : Add New Customers to the Customer table
**
**  Mod History: 
**    YourInitials 2017-06-30  Created Procedure
**
*/

begin

print 'Procedure [spAddNewCustomers]'
print '--------------------------------------------------';
print 'Step 01: Delete all records in the Staging Table';

DELETE FROM [newcustomers];

print '--------------------------------------------------';
print 'Step 02: This inserts new data into a Staging Table';

BULK INSERT [newcustomers] FROM 'C:\Users\Downloads\neCustomer.csv'
With 
   (FirstROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   );

print '--------------------------------------------------';
print 'Step 03: Insert the Staging table data into the Customer table';

INSERT INTO [CUSTOMER]
SELECT * FROM [newcustomers];

print '-----------------------------------------------';
print 'End of Procedure [spAddNewCustomers]';

end
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [spAddNewCustomers] TO public
GO
```

This is a stored procedure that will run three steps.
First step will delete all records out of your [newcustomers] Staging table.
Second step will Bulk import your csv data into your Staging table.
Third step will insert your staging table data into your [CUSTOMER] table.

Once you run this script, it will put the code in your Stored procedure library.
So you only run this Script once.

After that, to call the procedure, you get into MS SQL Server Management Studio (in the correct database) and type in the stored procedure name and hit the "Execute" button.

IE:

`spAddNewCustomers`

And as long as your neCustomer.csv file is in the right place (and isn't yesterdays data) all should run fine.

Hope that helps :)

PS, when you stated:

"...insert that new batch of data into 'customer' but **underneath** the previous data..."

When you insert data into an MS SQL database, the order to the data is not guaranteed.  MS has wizards that place data into the database in complicated ways.  You can't bank on the data being **underneath** the previous data.  To do so, you have to get into the world of Indexing or possibly row counters.

Although, one thing you may want to consider is:

Put a time stamp on your data records.  That way you'll know the date/time of an import.  Then, if you import data twice causing duplicates, you can identify the bad data and remove it easily.  Also, a time stamp will allow you to sort your data in ascending order upon retrieval, and then the new data will be **underneath** the old data. :)